# With CanvasJS charts, how can i have 2 charts on one page when using chart functions

Tags: canvasjs

Here is my code. Ive researched online and i only can use one window onload thing but i have functions in my charts that i cant remove. Ive tried to put the chart codes into one window onload function but to no avail. Ive also tried putting the chart functions with window.onload into two seperate pages and calling them into one php page, but it doesnt work (im assuming for the same reasons). Thanks :)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("bar", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: "Maximum, Minimum and Average Temperatures for the Hot Cars"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Temperature (C)",
        includeZero: true
    },
    legend: {
        cursor:"pointer",
        itemclick : toggleDataSeries
    },
    toolTip: {
        shared: true,
        content: toolTipFormatter
    },
    data: [{
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Maximum",
        color: "#fc0303",
        dataPoints: [
            <?php echo $black_max; ?>,
            <?php echo $white_max; ?>,
            <?php echo $red_max; ?>,
            <?php echo $clear_max; ?>,
            <?php echo $silver_max; ?>
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Minimum",
        color: "#0314fc",
        dataPoints: [
            <?php echo $black_min; ?>,
            <?php echo $white_min; ?>,
            <?php echo $red_min; ?>,
            <?php echo $clear_min; ?>,
            <?php echo $silver_min; ?>
        ]
    },
    {
        type: "bar",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Average",
        color: "#b503fc",
        dataPoints: [
            <?php echo $black_avg; ?>,
            <?php echo $white_avg; ?>,
            <?php echo $red_avg; ?>,
            <?php echo $clear_avg; ?>,
            <?php echo $silver_avg; ?>
        ]
    }]
});
chart1.render();

function toolTipFormatter(e) {
    var str = "";
    var total = 0 ;
    var str3;
    var str2 ;
    for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++){
        var str1 = "<span style= \"color:"+e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "\">" + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: <strong>"+  e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + "</strong> <br/>" ;
        total = e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + total;
        str = str.concat(str1);
    }
    str2 = "<strong>" + e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong> <br/>";
    str3 = "<span style = \"color:Tomato\">Total: </span><strong>" + total + "</strong><br/>";
    return (str2.concat(str)).concat(str3);
}

function toggleDataSeries(e) {
    if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
    }
    else {
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
    }
    chart.render();
}}

window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("line", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    zoomEnabled: true,
    title:{
        text: "Hot Cars Temperatures"
    },
    axisY:{
        title: "Temperature",
        lineColor: "#C24642",
        tickColor: "#C24642",
        labelFontColor: "#C24642",
        titleFontColor: "#C24642",
        includeZero: true,
        suffix: "C"
    },
    axisX: {
        title: "Time",
        titleFontColor:"#369EAD",
        lineColor:"#369EAD",
        tickColor:"#369EAD",
        labelFontColor:"#369EAD"  ,
        includeZero: true,
        suffix: " Mins"
      },
    toolTip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        itemclick: toggleDataSeries
    },
    data: [
        {
        type: "line",
        name: "White Temperatures",
        color: "#0d00ff",
        showInLegend: true,
        axisYIndex: 1,
        dataPoints: [<?php echo $white_data; ?>]
    },
    {
        type: "line",
        name: "Red Temperatures",
        color: "#ff1f1f",
        axisYIndex: 0,
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [<?php echo $red_data; ?>]
    },
    {
        type: "line",
        name: "Clear Temperatures",
        color: "#9d00ff",
        axisYIndex: 0,
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [<?php echo $clear_data; ?>]
    },
    {
        type: "line",
        name: "Silver Temperatures",
        color: "#bdbdbd",
        axisYIndex: 0,
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [<?php echo $silver_data; ?>]
    },
    {
        type: "line",
        name: "Black Temperatures",
        color: "#000000",
        axisYIndex: 0,
        showInLegend: true,
        dataPoints: [<?php echo $black_data; ?>]
    }]
});
chart.render();

function toggleDataSeries(e) {
    if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
    } else {
        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
    }
    e.chart.render();
}}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>    
<div id="line" style="height: 370px; width: 75%;"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="bar" style="height: 370px; width: 75%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) gets fired when the entire page loads, including its content (images, CSS, scripts, etc.). You can create any number of charts within window.onload. Refer CanvasJS [documentation](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/how-to/render-multiple-charts-in-a-page/) for tutorial on rendering multiple charts in a page.

Below is the working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("bar", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  title:{
      text: "Maximum, Minimum and Average Temperatures for the Hot Cars"
  },
  axisY: {
      title: "Temperature (C)",
      includeZero: true
  },
  legend: {
      cursor:"pointer",
      itemclick : toggleDataSeries
  },
  toolTip: {
      shared: true,
      content: toolTipFormatter
  },
  data: [{
      type: "bar",
      showInLegend: true,
      name: "Maximum",
      color: "#fc0303",
      dataPoints: [
          <?php echo $black_max; ?>,
          <?php echo $white_max; ?>,
          <?php echo $red_max; ?>,
          <?php echo $clear_max; ?>,
          <?php echo $silver_max; ?>
      ]
  },
  {
      type: "bar",
      showInLegend: true,
      name: "Minimum",
      color: "#0314fc",
      dataPoints: [
          <?php echo $black_min; ?>,
          <?php echo $white_min; ?>,
          <?php echo $red_min; ?>,
          <?php echo $clear_min; ?>,
          <?php echo $silver_min; ?>
      ]
  },
  {
      type: "bar",
      showInLegend: true,
      name: "Average",
      color: "#b503fc",
      dataPoints: [
          <?php echo $black_avg; ?>,
          <?php echo $white_avg; ?>,
          <?php echo $red_avg; ?>,
          <?php echo $clear_avg; ?>,
          <?php echo $silver_avg; ?>
      ]
  }]
});
chart1.render();

var chart2 = new CanvasJS.Chart("line", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  zoomEnabled: true,
  title:{
      text: "Hot Cars Temperatures"
  },
  axisY:{
      title: "Temperature",
      lineColor: "#C24642",
      tickColor: "#C24642",
      labelFontColor: "#C24642",
      titleFontColor: "#C24642",
      includeZero: true,
      suffix: "C"
  },
  axisX: {
      title: "Time",
      titleFontColor:"#369EAD",
      lineColor:"#369EAD",
      tickColor:"#369EAD",
      labelFontColor:"#369EAD"  ,
      includeZero: true,
      suffix: " Mins"
    },
  toolTip: {
      shared: true
  },
  legend: {
      cursor: "pointer",
      itemclick: toggleDataSeries
  },
  data: [
      {
      type: "line",
      name: "White Temperatures",
      color: "#0d00ff",
      showInLegend: true,
      axisYIndex: 1,
      dataPoints: [<?php echo $white_data; ?>]
  },
  {
      type: "line",
      name: "Red Temperatures",
      color: "#ff1f1f",
      axisYIndex: 0,
      showInLegend: true,
      dataPoints: [<?php echo $red_data; ?>]
  },
  {
      type: "line",
      name: "Clear Temperatures",
      color: "#9d00ff",
      axisYIndex: 0,
      showInLegend: true,
      dataPoints: [<?php echo $clear_data; ?>]
  },
  {
      type: "line",
      name: "Silver Temperatures",
      color: "#bdbdbd",
      axisYIndex: 0,
      showInLegend: true,
      dataPoints: [<?php echo $silver_data; ?>]
  },
  {
      type: "line",
      name: "Black Temperatures",
      color: "#000000",
      axisYIndex: 0,
      showInLegend: true,
      dataPoints: [<?php echo $black_data; ?>]
  }]
});
chart2.render();

function toolTipFormatter(e) {
  var str = "";
  var total = 0 ;
  var str3;
  var str2 ;
  for (var i = 0; i < e.entries.length; i++){
      var str1 = "<span style= \"color:"+e.entries[i].dataSeries.color + "\">" + e.entries[i].dataSeries.name + "</span>: <strong>"+  e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + "</strong> <br/>" ;
      total = e.entries[i].dataPoint.y + total;
      str = str.concat(str1);
  }
  str2 = "<strong>" + e.entries[0].dataPoint.label + "</strong> <br/>";
  str3 = "<span style = \"color:Tomato\">Total: </span><strong>" + total + "</strong><br/>";
  return (str2.concat(str)).concat(str3);
}

function toggleDataSeries(e) {
  if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
      e.dataSeries.visible = false;
  } else {
      e.dataSeries.visible = true;
  }
  e.chart.render();
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>    
<div id="line" style="height: 370px; width: 75%;"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="bar" style="height: 370px; width: 75%;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```